# How to set a duration limit to videos chosen from library

Tags: android, video, android-sdcard

I am trying to limit the duration of the videos that will be uploaded on the server.

I use this code to make the user choose a video from the gallery :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("video/*");
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.size() <= 0) {
Log.d(TAG, "no video picker intent on this hardware");
return;
}
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RETURN);
```

How to set a 1 minute as duration limit on the videos selected from the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("video/*");
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.size() <= 0) {
Log.d(TAG, "no video picker intent on this hardware");
return;
}
long maxVideoSize = 24 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, maxVideoSize);

startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RETURN);
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to limit to video duration to be no more than 1 minute ...but you gave me an idea thanks

Comment: you can also use MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

Comment: 24 * 1024 * 1024 might not be 10MB

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    try {
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    }

    mediaRecorder
            .setOutputFile(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/"
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME
                    + "/TempVideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 30 sec max of
                                            // twitter.
    // mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(14340032); // Set max file size ~ 7M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
            .getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            if ((what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED)
                    || (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)) {
                updateView();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Raj Suvariya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7454155/raj-suvariya) @raj-suvariya  try this